# ASP.NET 3.5 C# : Combine images in one download

Tags: c#, image, httphandler

I Would like to know if its possible to combine mulitple images in 1 download. On my homepage I'm showing 12 images which change depending on the country of the user.

I notice this takes a lot of time to download for some users and i would like to know if it's
possible to combine them into one download with an httphandler (in the way u can combina js and css) or even create 1 static image out of those 12.

For an example [check here](http://www.seetor.com)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make pretty good use of [CSS Sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/) in this case.  They're HTML/CSS, so not ASP.Net specific in any way.

The overall concept is instead of many images, you use one large image, to eliminate the multiple round-trips to the server to fetch images.  Then what you're doing is showing only a portion of the larger image where needed (as a background to the element), so in your `<a>`s you'd have something like this for styling:

```
.channel { 
  background: #FFFFFF url(SpriteMapUS.jpg); 
  width: 85px; 
  height: 55px; 
  display: block; /* Make the anchor render like a div, no more <img> tag */
}
```

Then on a particular channel, something like this:

```
.bloomberg { background-position: 0 0; }
.abcnews { background-position: -85px 0; }
.nasa { background-position: 0 -55px; }
.nasdaq { background-position: -85px -55px; }
//etc for the others...
```

And a channel would look like this:

```
<a href="..." class="channel abcnews"></a>
```

Read the [article I linked](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/) for a full run-down, but those are the overall concepts for sprite maps.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the comment. I'm aware of css sprites but they will not fit my needs. The images are shown random and their location of the image in row/column are also random. I will keep this in mind for sure but the maintainability is somewhat less with this aproach as these images do intend to change quite much . Thanks for your good answer though!